# Rails: fetch records at once for has_many and has_many :through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, associations

Given the following models:

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :given_loans,    :class_name => "Loan", :foreign_key => "lender_id"
  has_many :received_loans, :class_name => "Loan", :foreign_key => "borrower_id"
  has_many :borrowed_books, :class_name => "Book", :foreign_key => "borrower_id", :through => :received_loans
  has_many :own_books,      :class_name => "Book", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
end
```

**Book**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner,     :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
  has_many   :loans,     :foreign_key => "borrowed_book_id"
  has_many   :borrowers, :through => "loans",   :foreign_key => "borrowed_book_id"
end
```

**Loan**

```
class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :borrowed_book, :class_name => "Book", :foreign_key => "borrowed_book_id"
  belongs_to :borrower,      :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "borrower_id"
  belongs_to :lender,        :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "lender_id"
end
```

These relationships seem to work fine.

Now I'd like to query all books for a user, including both the borrowed books and the owned books, which I'm currently doing like this:

```
def books
  own_books + borrowed_books
end
```

This method naturally causes two SQL queries, though:

```
Book Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE ("books".owner_id = 1)
Book Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" INNER JOIN "loans" ON "books".id = "loans".borrowed_book_id WHERE (("loans".borrower_id = 1))
```

Furthermore I'm not able to run active record methods such as `limit` or order against this selection, which would be nice to have. After all I'm fetching the books from the same table.

*I'm assuming that there's a better (more "Rails'") and more efficient way of doing this. Anyone care to point me into the right direction*? Cheers!

---

P.S.: A possible solution that came to mind was to define a query for a `has_many :books` relationship, but that didn't seem quite right either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's what I ended up doing.*

Using the [meta_where](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) gem the following method is possible to improve the situation:

```
def books
  Book.includes(:loans).where({ "owner_id" => self.id } | { "loans.borrower_id" => self.id })
end
```

This method returns a relation object and produces only one SQL query. Any opinions where this method should be located? Right now I'm having it in the `User` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the model:

```
def as_json(options={})
super(include: { trades: { include:  :trades } })
end
```